# What's the purpose of ctx.write(Unpooled.EMPTY_BUFFER) in Netty proxy example

Tags: java, netty

In `HexDumpProxyBackendHandler` of Netty [proxy example](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/master/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/proxy/HexDumpProxyBackendHandler.java) , the code of the method `channelActive` likes following:

```
public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
    ctx.read();
    ctx.write(Unpooled.EMPTY_BUFFER);
}
```

My question is what's the purpose of `ctx.write(Unpooled.EMPTY_BUFFER)`? Is it necessary to send an empty TCP message frame after the channel active?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not reason and this was most likely missed to be removed. I will clean up the example to remove it. Thanks for let us know

Comment: There are still 28 cases where empty buffer is written in netty. Also in https://github.com/adamfisk/LittleProxy it's written with the comment `Writing an empty buffer to signal the end of our chunked transfer`. My proxy is doing funny stuff and I couldn't figure out why, are you sure it has no purpose? thanks.

Comment: @norman-maurer can you please take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58399274