# Netty and TCP - How to properly send an empty message

Tags: tcp, netty

We have a simple TCP server behind an AWS Network ELB (similar to Echo server with long-lived connections) written in Netty and I'm trying to implement a keep-alive mechanism similar to TCP keep-alive mechanism to keep our idle connections open. Unfortunately we cannot rely on TCP keep-alive mechanism since NELBs do not forward keep-alive TCP packets to the other side of the loadbalancer.
What I'm thinking to do is to watch for idle connections and send an empty string (empty byte array) to clients. What I did so far in the code is:

1. Add a `IdleStateHandler` with some timeout values
2. Register a `GprsKeepAliveHandler`, a sub class of `ChannelDuplexHandler`, overriding `userEventTriggered` method sending (`ctx.writeAndFlush`) the `Unpooled.EMPTY_BUFFER`.

This way, I expect to receive a RST packet if the connection is gone. Otherwise the connection will become active again.

The problem is Netty does not do anything with the empty message, it does not send any packets to the client (monitored with Wireshark). If I change the message to `Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(new byte[]{0})` I see what I'm expect to see.

Questions

1. I couldn't find a better way to achieve my objective (keep connections alive and detect dead connections). If there's a better way please let me know.
2. What is the proper way to send an empty message in Netty? (I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33030331) question but it didn't help)
3. If the issue is because of OS TCP stack behavior, is there a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Netty does not make any syscall in case of empty messages. (see [this](https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/9772))

Answer (score 0):

from my perspective you need to send something meaningful, because you try to do (e.g. ping/pong, heartbeating behavior). Also see [Is it is possible to force TCP socket to send 0 bytes in case of packet losses - python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53837322/is-it-is-possible-to-force-tcp-socket-to-send-0-bytes-in-case-of-packet-losses)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. At least the protocol does not forbid this. I hoped that Netty let me do it. But it seems it does not make any syscall in case of empty messages. (Also added one comment to the post you mentioned.)